# Getting XamlC error XFC0000 : Cannot resolve type "ContentView"

Tags: xaml, maui

I am working on migrating Xamarin.forms application to .net maui and I follow steps mentioned in Microsoft site,
change .csproj to Microsoft.NET.Sdk for forms csproj, droid csproj, iOS csproj,replace Xamarin.forms namespace with maui,add mauiprogram.cs,
Delete Xamarin.Forms and Xamarin.Essentials nuget references,
set build action for xcml file to MauiXaml, replace forms xmlns in XAML file with xmlns="`http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui`"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?\>

<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui" 

xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
```

When trying to build the forms project getting XamlC error XFC0000 : Cannot resolve type "ContentView", XamlC error XFC0000 : Cannot resolve type "ContentPage".

Comment: please [edit] your post so that it is readable

Comment: I recommend creating a new project with Maui template. Compare xaml, and csproj, with what you have.

Comment: @SreejithSree Yes. i have removed the nuget pacakge which is based on xamarin.forms.

Comment: @user20694704 I have started manual migration, upgrade assistant always showing errors.

Comment: i am also doing manual migration