# Xamarin.forms "Cannot resolve type" error after every installation

Tags: c#, windows, cross-platform, maui

I ran into one problem. Each time when I download Xamarin.forms through NuGet packages in Visual Studio, I'm unable to compile the code due to the error:

`"Cannot resolve type: Shell,  Cannot resolve type: ResourceDictionary Cannot resolve type: ContentPage..."`

I tried to download older versions which were suggested on the Microsoft forum and so on, but nothing happened. When I uninstall the package, everything works fine, however, after installation same error occurs. (Btw I'm running on windows machine)

Thanks in advance

I was trying to find an answer but was unsuccessful. I looked up this question: [Getting XamlC error XFC0000 : Cannot resolve type "ContentView"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74693009/getting-xamlc-error-xfc0000-cannot-resolve-type-contentview) but there is no answer.

Comment: Xamarin.Forms and MAUI are different frameworks.

Comment: You are using the Maui. Please do not use the Xamarin NuGet packages on the Maui platform.